# Conditional/dynamic array promise all

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a function with an array of promises, that array can have from 1 to X promises.

Those promises enter into the array based on conditionals.

I want to be able to distinguish from which API comes each result, and I can't realise a clean way to do it

```
let promises = [];

if (false) {
  let promise1 = request(toUrl);
  promises.push(promise1);
}
if (true) {
  let promise2 = request(toUrl);
  promises.push(promise2);
}

if (false) {
  let promise3 = request(toUrl);
  promises.push(promise3);
}

if (true) {
  let promise4 = request(toUrl);
  promises.push(promise4);
}

try {
  let result = await Promise.all(promises);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

So, if everything goes ok result will be an array of results. Not knowing which one of the conditionals was true, how do I know if result[0] is the result of promise1, promise2 or promise3?

Comment: Why dont you conditionally push urls to array ? And then simply  `Promise.all (urls.map (request))`

Comment: Adding urls will not give him at `Promise.all` `then` for which url was the request done

Comment: @Suren Srapyan you are wrong, please refer to MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I mean that after getting the result you have the result of the array of urls, but exactly for which urls you have, you don't know. I mean that `urls` added to the array with conditions. Yes you have for all of them if they were resolved, but actually which urls are added into the array you can't detect at Promise.all

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just add to the response of your `request(url)` another information about the promise like

```
const promise1 = request(url).then(res => ({ res: res, promise: 'promise1' }))
```

and at the `Promise.all()` you will get values of the promises in the above form and can detect which promises were resolved.

**Example**

```js
const promises = [];

if(true) {
   const promise1 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(res => ({ res: res, promise: 'promise1' }));
   promises.push(promise1);
}

if(false) {
   const promise2 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2').then(res => ({ res: res, promise: 'promise2' }));
   promises.push(promise2);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: cool, love it. one question more to clarify about promises, putting .then and calling the callback function into .then after a promise means that i'm executing the promise right?

Comment: When you create a Promise, it starts to execute already. Adding `then` does not mean that you execute it

Comment: I mean that request(url) if promises were functions is function, and request(url).then(res => res) is function(), am I right?

Comment: Both return you Promises, but the last one also adds some other work to it. If I understood you correct

Comment: oh I see, thanks for all your help man, really appreciate it, have a good morning!

Comment: @LucasJanon You too

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really works and helps me learn a new thing!

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion we can simplify the complexity of the problem by using following code -

```js
let promises = [];

let truthyValue = true,
  falsyvalue = true;
  
 let [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4] = await Promise.all([
    truthyValue ? request(toUrl) : Promise.resolve({}),
    truthyValue ? request(toUrl) : Promise.resolve({}),
    falsyValue ? request(toUrl) : Promise.resolve({}),
    falsyValue ? request(toUrl) : Promise.resolve({})
 ]);
 
 // promise1 will be called only when truthyValue is set
 if (promise1) {
  // do something
 }
 
  // promise2 will be called only when truthyValue is set
  if (promise2) {
  // do something
 }
 
  // promise3 will be called only when falsyValue is set
  if (promise3) {
  // do something
 }
   // promise4 will be called only when falsyValue is set
  if (promise4) {
  // do something
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, always a different quantity of async functions to call.
What I didn't want was to start the promises work before `promise.all()`.

So I collected function pointers in an array.

eg:

```
async function first() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=> setTimeout(resolve,1000,99));
}

async function second() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=> setTimeout(resolve,1500,100));
}

let x = [first, second];
// x is transformed into an array with then executed functions
await Promise.all(x.map(x=>x()))
```

Result is:

```
[
    99,
   100
]
```

hopefully this helps and I understood the mentioned problem ... :)

Answer (score 2):

I used an object map of promises with a name key in order to identify which resolve corresponds to which promise.

```js
const promises = {};

const mapResolveToPromise = res => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(promises).map(([key], index) => [key, res[index]])
);

promises.promise1 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
promises.promise2 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2');

Promise.all(Object.values(promises))
  .then(mapResolveToPromise)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.promise1.url);
    console.log(res.promise2.url);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why all the pushes, you can construct arrays inline.

```
doPromiseStuff = async ({ thing = true }) => {
  const urls = ['', '', '', ''];

  return await Promise.all([
    thing ? request(urls[1]) : request(urls[2]),
    thing ? request(urls[3]) : request(urls[4])
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed.